# Configuring osm2po to use maxspeed:seasonal:winter if available

Tags: openstreetmap, osm2po

In Finland, the speed limits on some roads are different in the winter. These roads are usually tagged with `maxspeed:seasonal:winter` in OpenStreetMap. Is there a way of configuring *osm2po* to use the value of `maxspeed:seasonal:winter` instead of `maxspeed` when overriding the default speeds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just modified my current version (upcoming 5.x to meet this requirement). In the meantime the only thing you can do is to overwrite the DefaultWayTagResolver with Java means.